# Querying GAE Datastore returns property types instead of values

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have stored data in the gae datastore, but when I query the data and reference the properties I seem to be getting a reference to the object rather than the value of the attribute.

```
class ClassDefinitions(db.Model):
    class_name = db.StringProperty
    class_definition = db.TextProperty

class FlexEntityAdminHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassDefinitions")
        definitions = query.fetch(1000, 0)

        for definition in definitions:
            logging.info("Name: %s", definition.class_name)
            logging.info("Def: %s", definition.class_definition)
```

When I reference definition.class_name I get:

```
<class 'google.appengine.ext.db.StringProperty'>
```

Instead of the value that I stored.  I know that it is getting stored because each time I add a new entry the number of results from the query increases by 1.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When creating the model, you need to create actual instances of the property type classes:

```
class ClassDefinitions(db.Model):
    class_name = db.StringProperty()
    class_definition = db.TextProperty()
```

(Note the `()`.)

Comment: Thanks, such an obvious mistake but I've been staring at it for hours!